# How to get any language alphabet?

Tags: linux, locale

Are there any utilities that can give me the alphabet of a specific language/locale (when the term "alphabet" makes sense)? Something like typing:

```bash
localeinfo 'de_DE.UTF-8' | grep 'alphabet'
```

and receiving:

```bash
"abc...äöüß"
```

Comment: The concept of "alphabet" is a greek description where the first letter is alpha and the second is beta. Greek is written in, well, the greek script. The names for the first and second letters came from ancient Phoenician alphabet . But there is no alphabet in chinese, cherokee, and hiragana  for example. There is no simple general answer to this question. Or, in other words, the mental structure that there is an alphabet for each script (Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, Devanagari, Chinese, Katakana) doesn't reflect the complexities of human languages.

Comment: @QuartzCristal you're right. I can restrict the question to the first group of languages ("non-hieroglyphic") or say that it's OK to use any of the "alphabet" sequence described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_alphabet). Actually, I need the solution only for the European languages, but formulated the question more generally.

Comment: Ar far as I know, there are some selections in Perl of Unicode properties that are similar to your request: `\p{Latin}` or `\P{Cyrillic}`. But those are still too broad IMO. If you accept the broad solution of listing all (Letter like) characters in one of the possible code-pages there is a closer to the goal solution. I mean: the characters in [ISO-8859-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7) for example. But that is, still, not specific enough for what you are asking. The letters in `ISO-8859-1` are used in many languages.

Comment: @cppbest hm, you say the German alphabet encompasses the umlauts, which I can agree to. Does the French alphabet include all é, è, ê, ë? Or are these just e with an accent? What about Hiragana, Katakana? These two Japanese alphabets are syllabic, so pretty close to a indogermanic phonetic alphabet, but a) contain different symbols for the same sound, and b) there's also a wealth of modifiers, but usually to only one of them, c) they're used in the same texts, next to each other, and next to a symbolic script (kanji) for different words.Does Japanese thus have all these characters as alphabet?